# Save the data of a click on an image in a table js

Tags: javascript, arrays, click

I have a code that when you click on an image it associates a point to it.

What I would like is that every time I click, the associated point on the image is stored in a table.

If I add 3 points on the image, let those 3 points be stored in a table.
Because afterwards I would like to be able to click on these points to be able to add information.

Thank you very much for your help, and sorry for my English.

Here is my code js

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var addPoint = false;
        $(".button").on('click', function () {
            addPoint = !addPoint // will toggle false -> true or true -> false;
        });

        $(document).click(function (ev) {

            if (addPoint == true && ev.pageY > 40 && ev.pageY < 990) {
                $(".div1").append(
                    $('<div></div>').css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: ev.pageY + 'px',
                        left: ev.pageX + 'px',
                        width: '20px',
                        height: '20px',
                        borderRadius: '20px',
                        background: 'blue',
                        color: 'white',
                        textAlign: 'center',
                    })
                );
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

```
<body>
    <button class="button">Add a point</button>
    <div class="div1">

        <img src="photo1.jpg" />

    </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the code below:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
        let count = 0
        let resultArray = []
        var addPoint = false;
        $(".button").on('click', function () {
            addPoint = !addPoint // will toggle false -> true or true -> false;
        });

        $(".div1").click(function (ev) {

            if (addPoint == true && ev.pageY > 40 && ev.pageY < 990) {
                $(".div1").append(
                    $('<div></div>').css({
                        position: 'absolute',
                        top: ev.pageY + 'px',
                        left: ev.pageX + 'px',
                        width: '20px',
                        height: '20px',
                        borderRadius: '20px',
                        background: 'blue',
                        color: 'white',
                        textAlign: 'center',
                    })
                );
                count = count +1
               $("#myTBody").append(
                 "<tr id='point"+count+"'><td>"+count+"</td><td>"+ev.pageX+"</td><td>"+ev.pageY+"</td></tr>"
                )
                let point = {
                   id:count,
                   x:ev.pageX,
                   y:ev.pageY
                }
                resultArray.push(point) // You could use this array to do something you want
                 $("#point"+count).on('click', function () {
                 var output = "ID :"+ $(this).children(":first").text()+"  X,Y :"+$(this).children().eq(1).text()+""+$(this).children().eq(2).text() 
                 $("#pointInfo").text(output)
                });
                
            }
        });
        
        

    });
```

```css
.div1 {
  width:200px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
}

tr:hover {
  background-color:yellow;
  cursor:pointer

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <button class="button">Add a point</button>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <table>
       <thead id="myTHead">
          <tr>
             <th>PointID</th>
             <th>X</th>
             <th>Y</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody id="myTBody">
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="pointInfo"><div>

</body>
```